# How do I map a drive from an Amazon EC2 instance to my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008

I am trying to map a drive from an Amazon EC2 Instance of Windows Server 2008.

I have tried doing this the standard way of entering the IP (public and private) into the server field. My main goal is for users to be able to use login credentials to access drives on the Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: ServerFault is probably the better place to ask this question. It looks like someone has already asked this question there: http://serverfault.com/questions/352950/mapping-a-local-drive-to-drive-on-windows-2008-server-running-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: I appreciate the input but I am lookin gfor a solution that does not involve using a VPN. I just want to be able to map the EC2 instances drive to my local machine using standard user credentials.